# Measuring Lithium ion cell voltage used to power Arduino via a boost module

Tags: arduino-nano, battery, adc

Can I measure lithium ion cell voltage with Arduino ADC which is used to power the same Arduino through a boost module (XL6009)? The output voltage of boost module is 9 volts.

Comment: Sidenote: why are you boosting the voltage to 9V (and presumably using the voltage regulator on the nano to bring it back to 5V)?

Comment: @Gerben Because the lithium ion cell voltage can be in the range of 3-4.2 volts depending upon the charge level. So to operate the analog circuit  (using LM358) and Arduino nano at a stable voltage I have to boost the input voltage. Plus the XL6009 module will keep the output voltage stable at 9V regardless of the input voltage.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of a library called [BatterySense](https://github.com/rlogiacco/BatterySense) and you can use it to achieve your goal. In the repository Readme you can also find wiring diagrams and usage examples, but to give you a rough idea...

1. Verify the negative side of your battery has continuity to the GND pin of your Arduino: you need to identify if the boost module is messing the common ground, but if you have continuity then you are fine
2. Add a connection from the battery positive terminal going into one of the Arduino analog pins
3. Use the BatterySense library to get the battery voltage and percentage level

Comment: Thanks so much OP and Roberto. I also want to measure a LiPo that is powering my Arduino. Great library, I've just checked it out. I suspect that I have the case where my battery negative terminal is not directly connected to GND, as part of the design, sot hat an over-discharge protection IC can do it's job. Any suggestions for that scenario? Here's the Circuit and PCB 
 https://easyeda.com/GreatScott/LiPoChargeProtectBoost_copy-3d9f4c3ddc7347d7861776340b9b90b7 which is linked to from GreatScott!'s excellent youtube video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fj0XuYiE7HU

Comment: I believe you might get more visibility if you post a proper question rather than a comment, may be referring to this question and answer in yours... I don’t know how you can work around with a non shared GND, but I’ll definitely interested in the answers you’ll get ;-)

Comment: Thanks Robert, that's a great suggestion. I'll experiment with measuring the voltage with and without the over-discharge protection IC, trying it anyway, as I suspect the arduino will only be measuring the voltage when it's actually on, and therefore connected to ground via the MOSFET that the protection IC turns on and off. If it gives weird results / there's some difference in the measured battery voltage, then I'll post a new question. Thanks again, will tag you / this!

Comment: Cool library guy. +1